# Java OCR implementation

Tags: java, ocr

This is primarily just curiosity, but are there any OCR implementations in pure Java? I'm curious how this would perform purely in Java, and OCR in general interests me, so I'd love to see how it's implemented in a language I thoroughly understand. Naturally, this would require that the implementation is open source, but I'm still interested in proprietary solutions, as I could at least check out the performance in that case.

I've seen a couple which can be used in Java (like [Asprise](http://asprise.com/home/)) but it doesn't seem that these are pure Java implementations... are there any?

Comment: @Robik First of all, while you're at it, you should also remove unnecessary thanks etc. And second, you should not edit in such an assumption, especially if OP is still active and you could simply comment - although it's likely to be true in this case... @ **rat** Just to clarify, did you mean asprise?

Comment: If you don't search for pure-Java approach, then perhaps building a JNI bridge (like [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/)) makes sense. My feeling is that OCR libraries are better represented in C++ world (OCRAD, GOCR, Cuneiform – see all [here](http://centurion.nfors.com/w/software/ocr)).

Comment: @rat - You are right - [Asprise OCR SDK for Java](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/java-ocr-api-overview.html) is not pure Java based. In fact, behind the scene, native code is used as OCR is a very computationally expensive process.

Answer (score 86):

I recommend trying the [Java OCR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/) project on sourceforge.net.  I originally developed it, and I have [a blog posting on it](http://www.roncemer.com/software-development/java-ocr).

Since I put it up on sourceforge, its functionality been expanded and improved quite a bit through the great work of a volunteer researcher/developer.

Give it a try, and if you don't like it, you can always improve it!

Comment: @Ron I've had a look at the project too. I did not find the demo and the GUI does various graphical operations but there are no instructions on how to get the actual character recognition going.

Comment: @Ron when I follow the link to your blog then I see a blank page.

Answer (score 11):

If you are looking for a very extensible option or have a specific problem domain you could consider rolling your own using the [Java Object Oriented Neural Engine](https://sourceforge.net/projects/joone/). Another [JOONE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JOONE) reference.

I used it successfully in a personal project to identify the letter from an image such as [this](http://www.gamerbytes.com/xnawordsoup.jpg), you can find all the source for the OCR component of my application on github, [here](http://github.com/dukedave/wordsolver/tree/2e03f0dcf7c9fcfef60d6df0dfd1036c3660a30d/src/ocr).

Comment: Most links are dead.

Answer (score 11):

We have tested a few OCR engines with Java like Tesseract,Asprise, Abbyy etc. In our analysis, Abbyy gave the best results.

Comment: Java API or Java implementations..?

Comment: Neither but there is a command line version to which you can talk using `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Neither Tesseract nor Abbyy are Java-based. They simply have APIs for Java.

Answer (score 6):

There are a variety of OCR libraries out there. However, my experience is that the  major commercial implementations, ABBYY, Omnipage, and ReadIris, far outdo the open-source or other minor implementations. These commercial libraries are not primarily designed to work with  Java, though of course it is possible.

Of course, if your interest is to learn the code, the open-source implementations will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Just found this one (don't know it, not tested, check yourself)

[Ron Cemer Java OCR](http://www.roncemer.com/software-development/java-ocr)

---

As you only need this for curiosity you could look into the source of this applet.

It does OCR of handwritten characters with a neural network

[Java OCR: Handwriting Recognition](http://www.heatonresearch.com/articles/42/page1.html)

Comment: @Matthieu Do you realize I answered this question 7 months before Ron posted?