# Looking for OCR SDKs for Forms and Docments

Tags: c#, java, ocr

My company want to use java to develop a document management project based on OCR technology. Who with OCR development experience can recommend which OCR SDK are better？

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation

Answer (score 1):

You will find it difficult to get Java support for commercial OCR libraries unless you can use Java to access the Windows DLL's as most good engines are Windows only.

You will have many more options with C# and C++.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731672/windows-ocr-and-icr-libraries/3734973#3734973 lists some commercial OCR engines that are available and give very good results.

OCR results will vary greatly depending on the input quality of your documents. This includes resolution, font size, image processing, image quality, hand print or machine print ?

There are good and bad OCR engines out there so I recommend testing lots of your documents before making a decision.