# Is it possible to use MODI for OCR in a java project?

Tags: java, project, modi

I am trying to implement OCR in my java project.
I need to read text from an image.
While browsing I came across lot of examples for using MODI in .NET project.
Can this be done using java?
If not possible can you suggest an alternate tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various Java-.NET interoperability tools. But I'd suggest you to refer to the following resources:

[Java OCR implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971344/java-based-ocr-sdk-api

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of Java wrappers for Tesseract OCR engine:

- [tesjeract](http://code.google.com/p/tesjeract/)
- [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sf.net)

Or you can simply use ProcessBuilder/Process to invoke Tesseract executable and read the output text file as it does in VietOCR.