# Where do I start for Text Pattern Recognition - Java Based

Tags: java, pattern-matching, ocr

I am seriously considering doing a Optical Character Recognition program. I am well versed with Java and would love to know about libraries available out there. Basically, I want to convert something like the following to text. I will need to give manual interruption to specify a pattern. For example, I would need to ask user to mark f in this text, so that I know where f occurs.

[image]

I am a newbie to this entirely, so I dont mind learning from scratch as well. Need guidance.

Comment: Some suggestions in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1813881/3009).

Comment: Are you looking toward rolling your own OCR, or looking for an already existing OCR software in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are thinking of coding an OCR program from scratch, reading up on techniques may be useful.  I found an [OCR Survey from 1996](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/fas-info/cs/CC/414/li/material/refs/OCR-survey-96.pdf) which reviews some of the popular techniques from a decade and a half ago.  Reading that might be helpful; track down papers it cites or papers which cite it.

Usually the process goes as follows:

```
find text
find characters in the text
extract features from the characters found
do pattern matching
report suspected character
```

While getting a user to annotate text is fun and exciting, finding a collection of handwriting which is already annotated might save you a lot of time, that way you can focus on the nuts and bolts of doing OCR rather than building your own database of annotated text.

To start with a slightly easier task you might want to consider building a system to detect handwritten digits.  The USPS produced a [corpus](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/data/) for developing systems to do this for zip code processing.  The link was something I found with a quick search.

Comment: I also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850717/what-are-some-popular-ocr-algorithms when searching SO for [OCR].  There's another survey linked there, as well as plenty of discussion

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use/look at a library, you could try the Google-endorsed [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/).