# How can I do OCR in Java?

Tags: java, ocr, jpeg, image-segmentation

we have taken a .jpg file of some text. and we want to create separate .jpg segment files of each character in that text. how is that possible in Java?

Comment: you're looking for OCR capabilities.  Search stack-overflow for 'java ocr'

Comment: What does this have to do with Engineering Students again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java OCR implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with these two links:

http://www.roncemer.com/software-development/java-ocr

and

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/