# Find character, in particular numbers, in photo - is there a framework?

Tags: java, image-processing, ocr

Currently I am searching for an appropiate way to find prices in an image. The images are colored and are taken with a camera or smartphone.
I already have done some proprocessing like color thresholding, morph. reconstruction and other steps to locate and crop the region where the prices are placed. 
Now I want to do the recognition of prices.

In our project we already have tried some OCR frameworks (to be precise Tesseract with Tessjeract and also JOCR), but the recognition of numbers in photos is very bad. We also have done some experiments with preprocessed images (color thresholding, opening, segmentation and so on). But with the tested frameworks no satisfiying results were reached.

We also considered that neural networks could be a good way, but all project members haven't enough knowledge about them and there is a very short space of project time. Now we are looking for a framework which is able to find numbers in (preprocessed) images.

Could anybody suggest a framework, favoured a Java framework, which could do this?

I would be pleased if there are some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there exists the framework that you, guys, need *.

But I did something pretty much the same thing (mobile app, with OCR functionality) with Neural Networks and it did give relatively good results.

I used Self-organized map ([Kohonen NN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohonen)), to my surprise it was not as resource greedy as I expected and it was pretty easy to design and code, a basic example is available [here.](http://www.heatonresearch.com/articles/7)

- [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971344/java-based-ocr-sdk-api)
- [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation) ... guys, you should have searched a bit...

Comment: The links you posted I also have found. And we also tested some of the mentioned OCR frameworks. The problem is that I haven't found a framework yet, which could find characters in a binary image which is produced from a photo and where the characters are not in a line and in front of a coloured background.

Comment: probably such a framework is not developed yet :D

Comment: It seems so :-), but I hoped that one exists. It looks like that we have to swallow the bitter pill and write our own solution.