# Turn Image into Text - Java

Tags: java, image, text, analyzer

This is an interesting topic. Basically, I have an image that contains some text. How do I extract the text from the image?

I have already tried many things, but everything I do is very tedious and usually does not work. I am simply wondering if there is a fairly easy way to do this.

I have come upon this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/. I have tried this for hours, but I cannot get it to take an `Image` and turn it into a `String` of text from the image.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You could also find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480831/java-ocr-api-open-source-on-eclipse/9481603#9481603

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to look into Java OCR implementations. Take a look at this question:
[Java OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation)

Comment: Thanks, do you know how well this works?

Comment: Haven't tried it personally, but it will depend a lot on the clarity of the text on the image you are parsing.

Comment: The text is extremely easy to read. I will look into this, thanks!

Comment: Can you supply me with code for how to make this work? I have fiddled around with it for hours and I cannot get it to take an image and make it into a String.

Comment: Please do not link to other questions in your answer, instead please flag as duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

[Tess4J](http://tess4j.sf.net), a JNA wrapper around Tesseract engine, supports APIs that take BufferedImage, File, or image data as input, and return String as output.

Comment: I know I'm commenting after 3 years but your answer shoul be the right ansswer 'javaOCR' has many problems but this API works very well.

Answer (score 2):

You need an OCR (optical character recognizer) library or write your own. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation) SO question.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how well this works?

Answer (score 0):

Try this character recognition library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/