# Number Recognition from Image

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I have got the Libraries for Number Recognition i.e tesseract
But i dont know how to use the DLLs with JAVA.

Comment: You need a library with java interface, try to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation

Comment: Please provide more details about what you want to achieve and what you have tried so far. If you present a _specific_ problem, you're more likely to get help.

Comment: I m trying remove characters and number from image. And i m at starting phase of my project..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Java JNA wrapper for Tesseract DLL that you can use: [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sf.net)

Be sure to call TessBaseAPI::SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789"); if you want to [recognize only digits](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ).

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use [jni](/questions/tagged/jni) or run the external process from Java. Have a look at [Issue 302: how to run tesseract-ocr in java application at Linux platform](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=302). Specifically check [tesjeract](http://code.google.com/p/tesjeract/).