# Handwriting recognition in java

Tags: java, package, ocr, handwriting

I am looking to use handwriting recognition and OCR in a piece of software I have made. I was wondering if anyone knows of any (up to date) packages that do OCR or handwriting recognition.

I am looking more for free packages, but I would also be interested in comercial ones.

I have looked at some other articles like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768664/recommendations-for-handwriting-recognition-libraries-packages-in-java) from '09 but I could not find any that seemed reasonable.

Would I be better off writing in C# instead, and make use of the built in Windows 7 handwriting analyzer?

Comment: There is a Java port of opencv. I don't know if there is already some ready-to-use handwriting recognition, but I guess that would be a good starting point for your search.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Tesseract OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) engine from google.This is probably one of the most accurate open source OCR engines available.