# How to read text from image in java

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java OCR implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation)

Hi I am working on a project for which there is a requirement to read the text written in image. I tried googling on this and could find some details on OCR. But not sure how to implement it in my application? Anyone has idea on how to do that? Do I need to add some API and use it in my code?

Any Sample example would be of great help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check out http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ seems to be in development and all...

Answer (score 0):

[Please find here](https://compilr.com/anothercollegekid/cded) the project of OCR example on an image "Pink.jpg"
which has the chars "Sample"

The project consists on 3 files:

```
OCR.java
OCED.java
Program.java
```

Download them and make your tests

Comment: Hi I tried the above link.. but it gives the output in the image format. But my requirement is I need to read the text from the image and store it in .txt format

Answer (score 0):

From the problem described it might be that you are looking for captcha in Java.

Maybe this will help: [jcaptcha](https://jcaptcha.atlassian.net/wiki/display/general/Home)