# Read Character Value from image through java program

Tags: java, image-processing

[image]

Hi All,

As showing i have an image with fields Username & City & Work as in the image. I just want to read these Character fields value from this image with java program.
If any one have any idea about this please let me know

thanks

Comment: just google `java captcha recognition`, or `java character from image recognition`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can google with Java Character recognition through image and there is also good way to do this with this [example.](http://asprise.com/product/ocr/download.php?lang=java) this jar you can use as for testing

Comment: it is good but if you publish your app then you need to purchase it. not accurate but too good as i search at all.

Answer (score 2):

[Tess4J](http://tess4j.sf.net), a Java wrapper of Tesseract engine, can recognize such images (after rescaling to 300 DPI).

Comment: Good one and now using this.
But there is some problem with some character like @, % so any idea how can we handle this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

You should start looking into character recognizing libraries like [shown here](http://www.javawhat.com/showCategory.do?id=2138003). also, look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation)

Answer (score 0):

To read the image you can use BufferedImage: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html

Once you have loaded the image you can run an OCR module to get its text. Here are some examples of OCR software sorted from better to worst: ABBYY (but it is not free), Tesseract, Java OCR, Asprise...

And that is all !!