# separating text and image regions from an image code

Tags: image, image-processing, imagej

Separating image and text regions from an image is a very old problem and many papers have been written about it. One of the recent ones can be found [here](http://www.cyut.edu.tw/~ijase/2006/4-3%28Microsoft%20Word%20-%20011-006-8%29.pdf).

But I didn't find any existing code for this. Before implementing one, I thought it might be a good idea to ask SO community if anyone knows of an existing one.

Please point me to an existing code (preferably Java) if you know.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation

Comment: @medPhys-pl: I don't think it's a duplicate. rivu is asking for a segmentation algorithm, not a full OCR.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read your PDF completely but from what I saw you can find a similar algorithm implemented in C# in AForge.Net. Converting the code to Java shouldn't be a big deal.

See [HorizontalRunLengthSmoothing Class](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f61451b0-4f33-9f34-ca89-fb95ca040614.htm) and [VerticalRunLengthSmoothing Class](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/249b205e-b7e5-5a70-0eef-65efa5e61da8.htm)

Comment: Thanks. I found that the closest of what I need to do is probably implemented in leptonica :http://tpgit.github.com/UnOfficialLeptDocs/leptonica/document-image-analysis.html?highlight=page%20segmentation