# Robust card detection/persecutive correction OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I currently have a method for detecting a card in an image and for the most part it works when the lighting is fairly consistent and the background is very calm.

Here is the code I am using to preform this operation:

```
    Mat img = inImg.clone();
    outImg = Mat(inImg.size(), CV_8UC1);
    inImg.copyTo(outImg);

    Mat img_fullRes = img.clone();

    pyrDown(img, img);

    Mat imgGray;
    cvtColor(img, imgGray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    outImg_gray = imgGray.clone();
    // Find Edges //

    Mat detectedEdges = imgGray.clone();

    bilateralFilter(imgGray, detectedEdges, 0, 185, 3, 0);
    Canny( detectedEdges, detectedEdges, 20, 65, 3 );

    dilate(detectedEdges, detectedEdges, Mat::ones(3,3,CV_8UC1));
    Mat cdst = img.clone();

    vector<Vec4i> lines;
    HoughLinesP(detectedEdges, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 60, 50, 3 );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        Vec4i l = lines[i];
        // For debug
        //line( cdst, cv::Point(l[0], l[1]), cv::Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 1);
    }
    //cdst.copyTo(inImg);

//    // Find points of intersection //

    cv::Rect imgROI;
    int ext = 10;
    imgROI.x = ext;
    imgROI.y = ext;
    imgROI.width = img.size().width - ext;
    imgROI.height = img.size().height - ext;

    int N = lines.size();
    // Creating N amount of points // N == lines.size()
    cv::Point** poi = new cv::Point*[N];
    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        poi[i] = new cv::Point[N];
    vector<cv::Point> poiList;
    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        poi[i][i] = cv::Point(-1,-1);
        Vec4i line1 = lines[i];
        for( int j = i + 1; j < N; j++ )
        {
            Vec4i line2 = lines[j];
            cv::Point p = computeIntersect(line1, line2, imgROI);

            if( p.x != -1 )
            {
                //line(cdst, p-cv::Point(2,0), p+cv::Point(2,0), Scalar(0,255,0));
                //line(cdst, p-cv::Point(0,2), p+cv::Point(0,2), Scalar(0,255,0));

                poiList.push_back(p);
            }

            poi[i][j] = p;
            poi[j][i] = p;
        }
    }

    cdst.copyTo(inImg);

    if(poiList.size()==0)
    {
        outImg = inImg.clone();
        //circle(outImg, cv::Point(100,100), 50, Scalar(255,0,0), -1);
        return;
    }

    convexHull(poiList, poiList, false, true);

    for( int i=0; i<poiList.size(); i++ )
    {
        cv::Point p = poiList[i];
        //circle(cdst, p, 3, Scalar(255,0,0), 2);
    }
     //Evaluate all possible quadrilaterals

    cv::Point cardCorners[4];
    float metric_max = 0;
    int Npoi = poiList.size();
    for( int p1=0; p1<Npoi; p1++ )
    {
        cv::Point pts[4];
        pts[0] = poiList[p1];

        for( int p2=p1+1; p2<Npoi; p2++ )
        {
            pts[1] = poiList[p2];
            if( isCloseBy(pts[1],pts[0]) )
                continue;

            for( int p3=p2+1; p3<Npoi; p3++ )
            {
                pts[2] = poiList[p3];
                if( isCloseBy(pts[2],pts[1]) || isCloseBy(pts[2],pts[0]) )
                    continue;


                for( int p4=p3+1; p4<Npoi; p4++ )
                {
                    pts[3] = poiList[p4];
                    if( isCloseBy(pts[3],pts[0]) || isCloseBy(pts[3],pts[1])
                       || isCloseBy(pts[3],pts[2]) )
                        continue;


                    // get the metrics
                    float area = getArea(pts);

                    cv::Point a = pts[0]-pts[1];
                    cv::Point b = pts[1]-pts[2];
                    cv::Point c = pts[2]-pts[3];
                    cv::Point d = pts[3]-pts[0];
                    float oppLenDiff = abs(a.dot(a)-c.dot(c)) + abs(b.dot(b)-d.dot(d));

                    float metric = area - 0.35*oppLenDiff;
                    if( metric > metric_max )
                    {
                        metric_max = metric;
                        cardCorners[0] = pts[0];
                        cardCorners[1] = pts[1];
                        cardCorners[2] = pts[2];
                        cardCorners[3] = pts[3];
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    // find the corners corresponding to the 4 corners of the physical card
    sortPointsClockwise(cardCorners);

    // Calculate Homography //

    vector<Point2f> srcPts(4);
    srcPts[0] = cardCorners[0]*2;
    srcPts[1] = cardCorners[1]*2;
    srcPts[2] = cardCorners[2]*2;
    srcPts[3] = cardCorners[3]*2;


    vector<Point2f> dstPts(4);
    cv::Size outImgSize(1400,800);

    dstPts[0] = Point2f(0,0);
    dstPts[1] = Point2f(outImgSize.width-1,0);
    dstPts[2] = Point2f(outImgSize.width-1,outImgSize.height-1);
    dstPts[3] = Point2f(0,outImgSize.height-1);

    Mat Homography = findHomography(srcPts, dstPts);

    // Apply Homography
    warpPerspective( img_fullRes, outImg, Homography, outImgSize, INTER_CUBIC );
    outImg.copyTo(inImg);
```

Where `computeIntersect` is defined as:

```
cv::Point computeIntersect(cv::Vec4i a, cv::Vec4i b, cv::Rect ROI)
{
    int x1 = a[0], y1 = a[1], x2 = a[2], y2 = a[3];
    int x3 = b[0], y3 = b[1], x4 = b[2], y4 = b[3];

    cv::Point  p1 = cv::Point (x1,y1);
    cv::Point  p2 = cv::Point (x2,y2);
    cv::Point  p3 = cv::Point (x3,y3);
    cv::Point  p4 = cv::Point (x4,y4);
    // Check to make sure all points are within the image boundrys, if not reject them.
    if( !ROI.contains(p1) || !ROI.contains(p2)
       || !ROI.contains(p3) || !ROI.contains(p4) )
        return cv::Point (-1,-1);

    cv::Point  vec1 = p1-p2;
    cv::Point  vec2 = p3-p4;

    float vec1_norm2 = vec1.x*vec1.x + vec1.y*vec1.y;
    float vec2_norm2 = vec2.x*vec2.x + vec2.y*vec2.y;
    float cosTheta = (vec1.dot(vec2))/sqrt(vec1_norm2*vec2_norm2);

    float den = ((float)(x1-x2) * (y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2) * (x3-x4));
    if(den != 0)
    {
        cv::Point2f pt;
        pt.x = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2) * (x3-x4) - (x1-x2) * (x3*y4 - y3*x4)) / den;
        pt.y = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2) * (y3-y4) - (y1-y2) * (x3*y4 - y3*x4)) / den;

        if( !ROI.contains(pt) )
            return cv::Point (-1,-1);

        // no-confidence metric
        float d1 = MIN( dist2(p1,pt), dist2(p2,pt) )/vec1_norm2;
        float d2 = MIN( dist2(p3,pt), dist2(p4,pt) )/vec2_norm2;

        float no_confidence_metric = MAX(sqrt(d1),sqrt(d2));

        // If end point ratios are greater than .5 reject
        if( no_confidence_metric < 0.5 && cosTheta < 0.707 )
            return cv::Point (int(pt.x+0.5), int(pt.y+0.5));
    }

    return cv::Point(-1, -1);
}
```

`sortPointsClockWise` is defined as:

```
void sortPointsClockwise(cv::Point a[])
{
    cv::Point b[4];

    cv::Point ctr = (a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3]);
    ctr.x /= 4;
    ctr.y /= 4;
    b[0] = a[0]-ctr;
    b[1] = a[1]-ctr;
    b[2] = a[2]-ctr;
    b[3] = a[3]-ctr;

    for( int i=0; i<4; i++ )
    {
        if( b[i].x < 0 )
        {
            if( b[i].y < 0 )
                a[0] = b[i]+ctr;
            else
                a[3] = b[i]+ctr;
        }
        else
        {
            if( b[i].y < 0 )
                a[1] = b[i]+ctr;
            else
                a[2] = b[i]+ctr;
        }
    }

}
```

`getArea` is defined as:

```
float getArea(cv::Point arr[])
{
    cv::Point  diag1 = arr[0]-arr[2];
    cv::Point  diag2 = arr[1]-arr[3];

    return 0.5*(diag1.cross(diag2));
}
```

`isCloseBy` is defined as:

```
bool isCloseBy( cv::Point p1, cv::Point p2 )
{
    int D = 10;
    // Checking that X values are within 10, same for Y values.
    return ( abs(p1.x-p2.x)<=D && abs(p1.y-p2.y)<=D );
}
```

And finally `dist2`:

```
float dist2( cv::Point p1, cv::Point p2 )
{
    return float((p1.x-p2.x)*(p1.x-p2.x) + (p1.y-p2.y)*(p1.y-p2.y));
}
```

Here are several test images and their results:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Sorry for the very lengthy post, however I am hoping someone can suggest a way I can make my method for extracting the card from the image more robust. One that can better handle disruptive backgrounds along with inconsistent lighting.

When a card is placed on a contrasting background with good lighting my method works nearly 90% of the time. But it is clear I need a more robust approach.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

**ATTEMPT of dhanushka's soloution**

```
Mat gray, bw;     pyrDown(inImg, inImg);
cvtColor(inImg, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
int morph_size = 3;
Mat element = getStructuringElement( MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size( 4*morph_size + 1, 2*morph_size+1 ), cv::Point( morph_size, morph_size ) );

morphologyEx(gray, gray, 2, element);
threshold(gray, bw, 160, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours( bw, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0) );

int largest_area=0;
int largest_contour_index=0;
cv::Rect bounding_rect;

for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
{
    double a=contourArea( contours[i],false);  //  Find the area of contour
    if(a>largest_area){
        largest_area=a;
        largest_contour_index=i;                //Store the index of largest contour
        bounding_rect=boundingRect(contours[i]);
    }
}

//Scalar color( 255,255,255);
rectangle(inImg, bounding_rect,  Scalar(0,255,0),1, 8,0);
Mat biggestRect = inImg(bounding_rect);
Mat card1 = biggestRect.clone();
```

Comment: [this paper](http://www.cs.stevens.edu/~ghua/publication/ICIP06.pdf)  you might find helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general approach would definitely be something like Rutger Nijlunsing suggested in his answer. However, in your case, at least for the provided sample images, a very simple approach like morphological opening followed by thresholding, contour processing and convexhull would yield the result you want. Use a scaled down version of the images for processing so that you don't have to use a large kernel for morphological operations. Below are the images processed this way.

```
    pyrDown(large, rgb0);
    pyrDown(rgb0, rgb0);
    pyrDown(rgb0, rgb0);

    Mat small;
    cvtColor(rgb0, small, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    Mat morph;
    Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(11, 11));
    morphologyEx(small, morph, MORPH_OPEN, kernel);

    Mat bw;
    threshold(morph, bw, 0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);

    Mat bdry;
    kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
    erode(bw, bdry, kernel);
    subtract(bw, bdry, bdry);

    // do contour processing on bdry
```

This approach will not work in general, so I would strongly recommend something like Rutger suggested.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got it working with white cards on nearly all backgrounds, but I cannot get it working for colored cards. Could you provide the code you used? I have updated my question with my attempt.

Comment: I've edited my post to give you some pointers. You need to do few changes to the code.

Answer (score 9):

The art of image processing is (in my 10+ years experience) just that: an art. No single answer exists, and there is always more than one way to do it. And it *will* definitely fail in some cases.

In my experience of working on automatically detecting features in medical images, it takes a long time to build to reliable algorithm, but in hindsight the best result is obtained with a relative simple algorithm. However, it takes a lot of time to *get* to this simple algorithm.

To get to this, the general approach is always the same:

- get started is to build up a large database of test-images (at least 100). This defines 'normal' images which should work. By collecting the images you already start thinking about the problem.
- annotate the images to build a kind of 'ground truth'. In this case, the 'ground truth' should contain the 4 corners of the card since these are the interesting points.
- create an application which runs over these images an algorithm and compares the result with the ground truth. In this case, the 'comparing with ground truth' would be to take the mean distance of the found 4 corner point with the ground truth corner points.
- Output a tab-delimited file which you call .xls, and therefore can be opened (on Windows) in Excel by double clicking. Good to get an quick overview of the cases. Look at the worst cases first. Then open these cases manually to try to understand why they do not work.
- Now you are ready to change the algorithm. Change something, and re-run. Compare new Excel sheet to old Excel sheet. Now you start realizing the trade-offs you have to make.

That having said, I think that you need to answer these questions during the tuning of the algorithm:

- Do you allow a little folded cards? So no completely straight lines? If so, concentrate more on corners instead of lines / edges.
- Do you allow gradual differences in lighting? If so, a local contrast-stretch filter might help.
- Do you allow the same color for the card as the background? If so, you have to concentrate on the contents of the card instead of the border of the card.
- Do you allow non-perfect lenses? If so, to which extend?
- Do you allow rotated cards? If so, to which extend?
- Should the background be uniform in color and/or texture?
- How small should the smallest detectable card be relative to the image size? If you assume that at least 80% of the width or height should be covered, you get robustness back.
- If more than one card is visible in the image, should the algorithm be robust and only pick one, or is any output ok?
- If no card is visible, should it detect this case? Building in detection of this case will make it more user friendly ('no card found'), but also less robust.

These will make the requirements and assumptions on the image to acquire. Assumptions on which you can rely are very strong: they make the algorithm fast, robust and simple if you choose the right ones. Also let these requirements and assumptions be part of the testing database.

So what would I choose? Based on the three images you provided I would start with something like:

- Assume the cards are filling the image from 50% to 100%.
- Assume the cards are rotated at most 10 degrees or so.
- Assume the corners are well visible.
- Assume the aspect ratio (height divided by width) of the cards to be between 1/3 and 3.
- Assume no card-like objects in the background

The algorithm then would look like:

- Detect in each quadrant of the image a specific corner with a corner-filter. So in the upper left quadrant of the image the upper left corner of the card. Look for example at http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/CVSSP/demos/corners/results3.html , or use an OpenCV function for it like `cornerHarris` .
- To be more robust, calculate more than one corner per quadrant.
- Try to build parallelograms with one corner per each quadrant by combining points from each quadrant. Create a fitness function which gives higher score to:

  - having internal angles close to 90 degrees
  - be large
  - optionally, compare the corners of the card based on lighting or another feature.

  This fitness function gives a lot of tuning possibilities later on.
- Return the parallelogram with the highest score.

So why using corner-detection instead of a hough-transform to do line detection? In my opinion the hough-transform is (next to being slow) quite sensitive to patterns in the background (which is what you see in your first image -- it detects a stronger line in the background then of the card), and it cannot handle a little curved lines that well, unless you use a larger bin size which will worsen the detection.

Good luck!