# Reading text data from JPG image

Tags: java, image, ocr, pixel

I want to read content(text data) from  jpg image. Can someone give me a sample java program to refer.

The image would be a white page. The text would be in black. How do I extract data(lines/alphabets) and print it.

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You may need to search for "OCR" with java.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation) for OCR in Java. Once you are able to pull out the text, doing manipulations on the text can be taken care of by using [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/). Also, in case you are interested in image metadata as well, [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention for products by ABBYY. For example there is [ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK](http://ocrsdk.com?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_term=reading-text-data-from-jpg-image&utm_campaign=smm) – cloud-based OCR technology. It has very high recognition accuracy, a lot of documentation and good support.

You can try to use it in several easy steps:
1. Create a free account
2. Create an application using [code samples for Java](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/code-samples?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_term=reading-text-data-from-jpg-image&utm_campaign=smm)

If you need additional help, use [ABBYY's forum](http://forum.ocrsdk.com?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_term=reading-text-data-from-jpg-image&utm_campaign=smm) or publish your questions in comments below.
I work for ABBYY and ready to help you.