# Convert pdf with images to text in a web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, web, machine-learning

What would be the best way to implement this service and make it available through an api? Would I need to train a machine learning algorithm or is it there a more simpler solution?

Who knows if there is any free service which would take a pdf with images and translate it to text that could be consumed by a web server?

I'm about to finish a Coursera course about Machine Learning, I know a bit about tensorFlow, but I'm not certainly an expert on machine learning.

I do know a lot about web development.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for something like tesseract? What languages do you have to work with? Do you want the client to do the legwork, or will the server? How clean are the images? Are we talking captcha images, camera images, or cleanly exported pdfs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java OCR implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation)