# How to Extract text from image in java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, text

Is there any simple way to extract Text from an image? I want to print that text in the console.

for instance, if I have an image as follows,

[image]

we should be able to print that 'TEXT' in the console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java OCR implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation)

Comment: would you please use google for such trivial questions? what you are looking for is called OCR (optical character recogintion)

Answer (score 2):

You should use OCR engine for this purposes.

Try https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract . It's an opensource engine.

Comment: is this possible without library ?