# OCR not reading characters properly from this image

Tags: java, image-processing, ocr

I am trying to read characters from the captcha image using OCR engine. Unfortunately, I am unable to get a proper result. The image is being read as

```
:
18<?.< rest of the content is trimmed due to evaluation restriction>.
```

Which OCR I should implement and use in Java so that every character is read with 100% accuracy.

[image]

Comment: Captcha are usually meant not to be read by OCR, so I'm not surprised you got something wrong..

Comment: It is hard for an OCR engine to read from CAPTCHA. Still, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation

Comment: AFIK, there is no OCR program with **100%** accuracy...(So far)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the image, it looks like a captcha. Instead of reading it as a whole you can segment the letters first using a library like OpenCV ([link](http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/07-image-segmentation.html)).(Maybe the findContours() [method](https://github.com/ahanin/opencv-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/tk/year/opencv/demo/filters/FindContours.java)) Once you have every letter seperately, you can apply your OCR and then combine the results obtained.